# Enabling extension properties on Azure AD users

Tags: azure, entra-id, extension

We're running a pretty standard hybrid environment with a local AD that syncs to Azure AD. I've been tasked with adding some information into an attribute that isn't currently supported in Azure (otherHomePhone).

I've done the following steps:

- Added data into the attribute
- Added the attribute in AAD Connect along two other attributes that are currently being synced as well
- Done a full sync (both delta and initial)
- I can see the attribute is being synced if I run the "Get-AzureADExtensionProperty"

But, it is not being applied to any users. Is there something I'm missing? As written above, we have to other attributes that are synced this way, and they are working with no issues.

Comment: And to make matters worse/better, I've just enabled "extensionAttribute5" and it synced immediatly, as I'd have expected the other attribute to do as well.